# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when creating shaded jar with minimizeJar option

Tags: java, maven, jar

I am getting the error, when creating the shaded jar with maven-shade plugin. I tried debugging the error with mvnDebug but no helps. My end goal was to minimize the size of the jar. Any other option other than minimizeJar also welcomed.

Thanks in advance

```
Error creating shaded jar: 6952
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:582)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error creating shaded jar: 6952
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.mojo.ShadeMojo.execute(ShadeMojo.java:551)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6952
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.vafer.jdependency.Clazzpath.addClazzpathUnit(Clazzpath.java:94)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.filter.MinijarFilter.<init>(MinijarFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.mojo.ShadeMojo.getFilters(ShadeMojo.java:745)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.mojo.ShadeMojo.execute(ShadeMojo.java:471)
    ... 21 more
```

Comment: You have more than probably hit a bug with the shade plugin, and therefore should report it. With all the relevant code, of course, and the exact versions of whatever maven version and shade plugin you are using. Also, try [gradle](https://gradle.org).

Comment: Moving to gradle cannot be done immediately (Not my own project). So we have to live that maven atleast for some time.

Comment: I had this problem because I was using an old version of the Maven Shade Plugin (1.7 which has been outdated for years). I solved it by changing my plugin to the last stable version.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your shade plugin version. I encountered the exception in version 2.2 ,solved it in vresion 3.0.0. It is an [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MSHADE-107)